# wp_query not working with post_type

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I have two machines: local and deployment.

On my local machine I have the code:

```
$all_prods = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'product',
);

dump(query_posts($all_prods));
```

The result I'm getting is my three products, that I've created earlier.
But the same code on deployment machine returns an empty array despite of the website has many products in it.

I thought that somehow deployment machine has the other prefix for it's post type, than my local one, but when I type on deployment machine:

```
$prod = wc_get_product(440);
dump($prod);
```

I get **WC_Simple_Product** object with field **"post_type"** equal to **"product"**. How can I debug it?

Comment: do you have the same plugins with same configurations on the 2 websites ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

```
$query = new WP_Query();
$all_prods = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'product',
);
$query = new WP_Query($all_prods);
echo $query->request . '<BR>';
```

The output was different on 2 machines, there was a problem with a multilanguage plugin that automatically added a second table and made inner join with it.

Answer (score 3):

First I would state that in most cases the `query_posts` should be avoided!

> This function will completely override the main query and isn’t
>   intended for use by plugins or themes. Its overly-simplistic approach
>   to modifying the main query can be problematic and should be avoided
>   wherever possible.

I would suggest transfer your query with WP_Query and try something like this:

```
$all_prods = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'product',
);
$query = new WP_Query($all_prods);

while ($query->have_posts()) {
    $query->the_post();
    $post_id = get_the_ID();
    echo $post_id;
}
```

For the Debug part, I would use the `get_post($post_id);` to verify that we talk about the same post_type.

Comment: Thank you, for trying to help me. I've tried it with new WP_Query too but have_posts() returned false. I think, I,ve finally found where the bug was.

Comment: 1) Do you have any Loop/ WP_query before this? 2) IS any plugin overriding the WP_Query ?